# quering remote database using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have used sp_addlinkedserver to access the remote machines db now i am writing queries explicitly on database like,

select * from  [server\instance].database.owner.tablename

Now with this,

1. [Server\instance] : this has to be provided explicitly
2. [database] : can we find databases on specified instance using query like ms_ForEachDB ?
3. [owner] : Can we find the database owner name using query ?

If these values are found using queries do we need to use EXEC() to execute this or we can still achieve it using nice queries ?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "nice" format you mention is simply a 4 part object reference.

```
select * from [server\instance].database.owner.tablename
```

3 part

```
select * from database.owner.tablename
```

2 part

```
select * from owner.tablename
```

If you want to dynamically change any of the server, db or schema values then you have one option:

```
EXEC (@sqlstring)
```

However, if you only access stored procs remotely...

```
DECLARE @RemoteSP varchar(500)

SET @RemoteSP = '[server\instance].database2.schema.proc2'
EXEC @RemoteSP @p1, @p2, @p3 OUTPUT

SET @RemoteSP = '[server\instance].database1.schema.proc1'
EXEC @RemoteSP @p4, @p5, @p6 OUTPUT
```

However, changing the components of the object reference makes no sense arguably: if you know you're going to query a table then just call that table in that database...

Comment: Do I need linked server to run such query?

Answer (score 2):

you should make a query string and then run it by `exec()` function.

getting server name :

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

getting current db name :

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `EXEC` you could use something like `select * from openquery(MyLinkedServer,@sql)` THough i prefer `EXEC(@sql) AT MyLinkedServer`

But all work

Answer (score 0):

If it happens that you need to use some sort of **variable** in your arguments(e.g. collect remote's server updates since yesterday):

```
DECLARE @yesterday NVARCHAR(20) = '2016-09-23 08:16:20';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM database.targetTable AS origin
                          WHERE origin.columnWithDateTime >'''+@yesterday+''';';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC(@sql) AT linkedServer
```

______
Where:

> *database.targetTable* : For some reason SSMS 2008 R2 returns error if you describe it as [database].[targetTable], and i don't know why that happens.
>    **@yesterday**: Is the variable you want to insert (this case, a string containing datetime-like element)
>   **PRINT @sql**: Just to verify if the quotes are correctly placed. 
>   **columnWithDateTime**: Should be a column with *datetime* format (e.g. "timestamp", or similar to the **@yesterday** variable format.

"OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.": [See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) (MSDN: OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)).