# Run query for each element in array or list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, automation, database-administration, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to monitor all connections that hit our databases.

In order to do so I created this query:

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS [ServerName]
             ,NAME AS DatabaseName 
             ,COUNT(STATUS) AS [NumberOfConnections]
             ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
             ,hostname
             ,program_name
             ,loginame
FROM sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY NAME,hostname ,program_name ,loginame
GO
```

which returns me exactly what I want on my local computer:

Very good, the `ServerName` is there, `DatabaseName` too, the `NumberOfConnections` too, etc...

But what if I want to run it to a remote server? In my lab in fact I have a remote server which is called `[TESLABSQL02T]`, let's see if I can [query it remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347100/quering-remote-database-using-sql-server):

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS [ServerName]
             ,NAME AS DatabaseName 
             ,COUNT(STATUS) AS [NumberOfConnections]
             ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
             ,hostname
             ,program_name
             ,loginame
FROM [TESLABSQL02T].master.sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN [TESLABSQL02T].master.sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY NAME,hostname ,program_name ,loginame
```

That's cool: now I want to monitor all my network!

**Here is when things get spicy:** I want to automate this in a job that runs every 10 minutes and that can query around 30 servers.

Let's try with 2 servers first `[TESLABSQL01T]` and `[TESLABSQL02T]`:

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, ServerName varchar(50))
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'[TESLABSQL01T]'),(2,'[TESLABSQL02T]')
select * from @myTableVariable


SELECT @@ServerName AS [ServerName]
             ,NAME AS DatabaseName 
             ,COUNT(STATUS) AS [NumberOfConnections]
             ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
             ,hostname
             ,program_name
             ,loginame
FROM (select ServerName from @myTableVariable).master.sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN (select ServerName from @myTableVariable).master.sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY NAME,hostname ,program_name ,loginame
```

Unfortunately no joy :(

The query is giving me an `Incorrect syntax` near the `FROM` and the `LEFT JOIN`.

How can I make this query to run once on each remote server every 10 minutes?

Should I use a list, an array, a temp table, a normal table?

I hear about `FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor` , could that be an option?

Dynamic Query?

...every suggestion is valid. Thank you.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK, I removed the images. The problem is that creating a table with the code in StackOverflow is a pain. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I found a website that could help me format the tables: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# . I will use that from now on. I believe StackOverflow should sponsor this or copy the same same tool and make it available in the editor

Comment: Stackoverflow does support tables https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the syntax error you have to create an dynamic query using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @ServerName varchar(50), @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, ServerName varchar(50))
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'[TESLABSQL01T]'),(2,'[TESLABSQL02T]')
select * from @myTableVariable

Declare VarCursor cursor for
Select ServerName from @myTableVariable
Open VarCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM VarCursor INTO @ServerName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @DynamicSQL='SELECT @@ServerName AS [ServerName]
                 ,NAME AS DatabaseName 
                 ,COUNT(STATUS) AS [NumberOfConnections]
                 ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
                 ,hostname
                 ,program_name
                 ,loginame
    FROM '+@ServerName+'.master.sys.databases sd
    LEFT JOIN '+@ServerName+'.master.sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
    WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
    GROUP BY NAME,hostname ,program_name ,loginame'
    

    EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM VarCursor INTO @ServerName
END
CLOSE VarCursor
DEALLOCATE VarCursor
```

But for this query you have to ensure that you have privileges in all your servers or that you have linked servers in your principal SQL Server engine

Comment: You teach me `FETCH NEXT`, thank you @Isaac

Comment: If I run `sp_who2` on the remote server I see my user connected with SSMS in a `DORMANT` state. Is there a way to disconnect my user? Thank you again

Comment: but it says `Cannot use KILL to kill your own process.`