# SELECT @@ServerName on remote server returns local @@ServerName

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting, nameservers

I have two servers `[TESLABSQL01T]` & `[TESLABSQL02T]` and I want to monitor their connections remotely.

A user yesterday [suggested me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67928407/run-query-for-each-element-in-array-or-list/67929084#67929084) a query that could help me out and the query is indeed working:

```
DECLARE @ServerName varchar(50), @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, ServerName varchar(50))
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'[TESLABSQL01T]'),(2,'[TESLABSQL02T]')
-- select * from @myTableVariable

Declare VarCursor cursor for
Select ServerName from @myTableVariable
Open VarCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM VarCursor INTO @ServerName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @DynamicSQL='SELECT @@ServerName AS [ServerName]
                 ,NAME AS DatabaseName 
                 ,COUNT(STATUS) AS [NumberOfConnections]
                 ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
                 ,hostname
                 ,program_name
                 ,loginame
    FROM '+@ServerName+'.master.sys.databases sd
    LEFT JOIN '+@ServerName+'.master.sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
    WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
    GROUP BY NAME,hostname ,program_name ,loginame'
    

    EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM VarCursor INTO @ServerName
END
CLOSE VarCursor
DEALLOCATE VarCursor
```

The problem is that the qiery is returning `[TESLABSQL01T]` as `@@ServerName` on my local server but is also returning `[TESLABSQL01T]` for the remote `@@ServerName`.

[image]

This is wrong, it should return `[TESLABSQL02T]`.

Comment: The query is running on your local machine even if it's connecting to a remote machine for one or more of it's tables.

Comment: Yep, is there a workaround? Any table in `master` that holds the value of `@@ServerName`?

Comment: The simple and obvious is to just use the variable you're already using to substitute the value into the `FROM` clause, e.g. `SELECT ''' + @ServerName + ''' AS [ServerName]`, unless you're trying to address some issue where locally registered remote server names won't match the remote server.

Comment: Uh, I needed `'''` not  `'`. You can post it as an answer if you want. Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@ServerName` will always give you the local server name unless you execute the query via `OPENQUERY`.

If you want to use the same variable `@ServerName` as you use for the dynamic query (the linked server name) then just change your dynamic SQL to use it.

```sql
    SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerName, '''') + ' AS [ServerName]
```

If you want the name that the *remote* server uses for itself, then you could use a correlated subquery within the dynamic part:

```sql
    SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT (SELECT name FROM sys.servers srv WHERE srv.server_id = 0) AS [ServerName]
```